# Expressing linear transforms using linear functionals: is this possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Work over a fixed but arbitrary field.

Let $Y$ and $X$ denote finite-dimensional vectorspaces, and let $y \in Y^n$ denote a sequence of elements of $Y$, where $n$ is a natural number.

It seems likely that for all linear transforms $\varphi : Y \leftarrow X$ such that the image of $\varphi$ is included in the span of $y$, there exists a sequence $f \in (X^*)^n$ such that $$\mathop{\forall}_{x \in X}\left\{\varphi(x) = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_{<n}}f_i(x)y_i\right\}$$

It also seems likely that if $y$ is linearly independent, then the sequence $f$ is unique.

> **Question.** Is any of this true? If so: how do we know that? (proof request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly we can assume that $y$ spans $Y$ (otherwise replace $Y$ with $Z = \operatorname{span} \{ y_i : 0 \leqslant i < n\}$). Then some subsequence of $y$ is a basis of $Y$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $\{ y_i : 0 \leqslant i < m\}$ is a basis of $Y$. Let $\{\psi_i : 0 \leqslant i < m\}$ be the dual basis of $\{ y_i : 0 \leqslant i < m\}$, so we have $\psi_i(y_j) = \delta_{ij}$ with the Kronecker-$\delta$. Then define

$$f_i = \psi_i \circ \varphi$$

for $0 \leqslant i < m$ and $f_i = 0$ for $m \leqslant i < n$. Since $\{ y_i : 0 \leqslant i < m\}$ is a basis of $Y$, we can write

$$\varphi(x) = \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} c_j(x)\cdot y_j\tag{1}$$

in a unique way for every $x\in X$, and hence we have

$$f_i(x) = \psi_i(\varphi(x)) = \psi_i\Biggl(\sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} c_j(x)y_j\Biggr) = \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} c_j(x)\psi_i(y_j) = \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} c_j(x)\delta_{ij} = c_i(x),$$

so indeed

$$\varphi(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{m-1} f_i(x)y_i = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} f_i(x)y_i,$$

as desired. The uniqueness of the coefficients in $(1)$ shows that the representation

$$\varphi = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} f_i\otimes y_i$$

is indeed unique if $y$ is linearly independent (that is, is a basis of its span). Of course the representation is not unique if $y$ is linearly dependent.

Note that only the finite-dimensionality of $Y$ (resp. $Z$) was used, whether $X$ is finite-dimensional or not plays no role.

Answer (score 1):

There's a general result which helps to see this quite easily. For a compact operator $T:H_1 \rightarrow H_2 $ from one Hilbert space into another, there's the spectral representation theorem:

$$Tx = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \lambda_k \langle x ,e_k\rangle f_k,$$

where $\lambda_k$ is the sequence of eigenvalues of $|T|= (T^*T)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $e_k,f_k$ are series of vectors in $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively.

For the finite-dimensional case note that we can identify each of your vector spaces with the Hilbert space $\mathbb C^n$ of appropriate dimension with the standard scalar product. Furthermore, the series above of eigenvalues is in fact just sum a with $n$ summands, as $|T|$ has $n$ eigenvalues. The functionals you're looking for are the maps $x \rightarrow \langle\cdot,e_k\rangle$.

There are surely also other ways, such as representing the linear map as a matrix and writing the matrix as a product of appropriate vectors.

Comment: Thanks. But does this only work when the background field is R or C?

Comment: I wouldn't say 'only', but I can't qualify this statement further. Someone else with expertise in operator theory on other vector spaces might be able to qualify this statement further. Usually, the notion of Hilbert and Banach spaces restricts yourself to real and complex vector spaces. Which vector spaces are you considering?

Comment: I was hoping for a proof that works over any field, but perhaps the existence of a Hilbert-space answer to my question is a subtle hint from nature that really, much of the theory of Hilbert theory works over *any* field. I don't quite know how, but perhaps we should be trying to write down axioms for the dot product that don't involve an order relation; so in particular, we need to find something different to $\langle x,x\rangle \geq 0.$ Perhaps assuming that $\langle x,x\rangle$ can be expressed as a sum-of-squares is the correct approach, or something like that.